# Javassist: getFileName returns null

Tags: java, ant, javassist

When I compile my project with Ant, the getFileName method of the MethodCall class of javassist returns null, but when I compile it with javac file by file it returns the file where the method is called. Why is this happening?

Here is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Tracer" default="jar" basedir=".">
    <target name="init" description="Creates the directory where the compiled classes will be stored">
        <mkdir dir="classes" />
    </target>
    <target name="compile" description="Compiles the classes" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="Creates the project jar">
        <jar destfile="tracer.jar" basedir="classes">
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java" />
            <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="clean" description="Deletes the compiled classes">
        <delete dir="classes" />
        <delete file="tracer.jar" />
    </target>
    <target name="test" description="Target for building in Travis-CI" depends="compile" />
</project>
```

Comment: Did you compare the jars ?

Comment: When I used javac I didn't create a jar, but the jar created by ant contains the same thing as the file system after compilation.

Comment: And there is your problem. Javassist cannot locate the class when it does not know about the jar.

Comment: How should I do it then? I've already tried adding the jar to the classpath of javassist (ClassPool.appendClassPath) and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: From another user: I am facing same problem. .. Can you please share me as how to enable debug flag in ant.

Comment: Check it here, in the compile target https://github.com/AfonsoFGarcia/Trace/blob/develop/build.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

In order for javassist to get the file name and line numbers it needs to have debug info enabled, and ant does not have it on by default.

So, the solution is to enable debug info in ant.